# Woocommerce "new order" email not sending

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, wpml

I am trying to solve an issue concerning my woocommerce emails. When an order is placed, the "new-order" email for the admin is not sent from my site, yet the customer receives the confirmation. Plus, if I cancel an order from my wordpress, the admin receives the email "order cancel".

After checking a bit on every website, my problem still exists. I was able to set de debug.log file on the ftp and the error that appears is as followed:

> WordPress database error Column 'subject' cannot be null for the query INSERT INTO `wp_'XXXXXX'_wpml_mails` (`mail_id`, `timestamp`, `host`, `receiver`, `subject`, `message`, `headers`, `attachments`, `error`, `plugin_version`) VALUES (NULL, '2018-05-12 16:37:27', '', '', NULL, '

Is it a problem with WPML (multilingual plugin) or with the server? with woocommerce?

Thanks for any help or advice that could allow me to resolve this problem as it causes a big block into my shop...

Comment: You should try to translate to English the error message to improve the chances to get help. I'm don't know much about Woocommerce but you got a lot of empty and null values there (One is causing the exception to be thrown). You should check the email settings.

Comment: Are you able to send normal email via server?

Comment: Actually all emails to the admins are not sent.... Any ideas?

Comment: @KrishnaKavoor yes I'm able to send emails to the customer and to the admin when someone uses a contact form. thanks

Comment: @RubioRic I set up sendgrid to send my emails. Which settings are you talking about ? The woocommerce emails' settings ? or where else? thanks

Comment: As I said, I don't know much about WooCommerce, sorry. Somehow subject is being set to NULL and WordPress does not like it. I have guessed that being a generic email, in some place you have defined that subject.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, and I've solved it by editing the `woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php` file:

in lines `28-34` I've removed the `if` condition, and left only the part that is within the `else`. I've started to get admin e-mails again, but the same error message still appear, and the e-mail arrive with no subject.

EDIT:
The plugin that is in causing for `no subject` is `WPML Media` it's a known issue.
You can find the instructions for a work around in this [WPML open support ticket](https://wpml.org/errata/new-order-email-subject-shows-placeholders-instead-of-site-title-and-date-since/) as they say, this is a work around until the next `WooCommerce Multilingual` plugin update will be released.